# Is this a Correct Insertion Sort?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, insertion

This is my attempt at an insertion sort in Python:

```
def insert(alis):
    for i in range(1,len(alis)):
        currel = alis[i]
        j = i
        while j > 0 and alis[j]<alis[j-1]:
            alis[j] = alis[j-1]
            alis[j-1]= currel
            j=j-1
    print (alis)

alis = [3,2,6,2,1,678,23,98]
insert(alis)
```

It seems to work but the thing that puzzles me is, say

```
alis = [4,3,2,1]
```

After `i = 1`, `alis = [3,4,2,1]`. So when `alis[2]` is set to `4`, won't that change the value of `currel` from `2` to `4`? So you'd get `[3,4,4,1]`? But that doesn't seem to make the sort go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The `alis` list contains references to other objects; `alis[2]` references the `int` object  `4`. Setting `currel = alis[2]` creates another reference to that same object.

Changing `alis[2]` to reference another object does not affect `currel`, however. You are not changing the object `4`, you are changing what the list object references. As such, `currel` doesn't change. `currel` continues to reference the object `4`, unchanged.

You may want to read the (excellent) explanation Ned Batchelder gives in his Python Conference 2015 presentation: [*Python Names and Values*](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html). You can also use pythontutor.com to visualise what happens with your variables; see [your code on that site](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def+insert%28alis%29%3A%0A++++for+i+in+range%281,len%28alis%29%29%3A%0A++++++++currel+%3D+alis%5Bi%5D%0A++++++++j+%3D+i%0A++++++++while+j+%3E+0+and+alis%5Bj%5D%3Calis%5Bj-1%5D%3A%0A++++++++++++alis%5Bj%5D+%3D+alis%5Bj-1%5D%0A++++++++++++alis%5Bj-1%5D%3D+currel%0A++++++++++++j%3Dj-1%0A++++print+%28alis%29%0A%0Aalis+%3D+%5B3,2,6,2,1,678,23,98%5D%0Ainsert%28alis%29%0A&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=0).

Comment: But since currel is linked to alis by 'i', wouldn't the alteration in alis effect currel?

Comment: It is *not* linked to `alis`. It is linked to the value that `alis[i]` *also* links to.

Comment: Sorry man, but I still don't get it.
But, from a different perspective, am I correct in saying that the currel stays the value that it set before the while loop because you have not gone back and updated currel after the while loop?
By this rationale, the value of currel stays the same, until we move to the next value of i, so the whole system works.

Comment: Yes, your sort works just fine; you are just making a wrong assumption about assignments.